# Different ways to import files into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, import, hdfs

I want to know what are the different ways through which I can bring data into HDFS.

I am a newbie to Hadoop and was a java web developer till this time. I want to know if I have a web application that is creating log files, how can i import the log files into HDFS.

Answer (score 10):

There are lot's of ways on how you can ingest data into HDFS, let me try to illustrate them here:

1. `hdfs dfs -put` - simple way to insert files from local file system to HDFS
2. HDFS Java API
3. [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) - for bringing data to/from databases
4. [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/) - streaming files, logs
5. [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) - distributed queue, mostly for near-real time stream processing
6. [Nifi](http://nifi.apache.org/) - incubating project at Apache for moving data into HDFS without making lots of changes

Best solution for bringing web application logs to HDFS is through Flume.

Comment: Thank you @Ashrith..can you please tell me that in a company with Bigdata services , how do they import data into HDFS ? Do they use the same methods which you mentioned here.

Comment: Which tool is used depends on the type of data that you want to import to HDFS. That being said , you can also have a pipeline for importing data that uses more that one tool . eg:  Flume+Kafka

Comment: Thank you @clyde D'cruz..If my company uses CRM, ERP and a server for data storage what can be the ways to import data from these systems into hdfs

Comment: @Gaurav yes the tools mentioned above are the ones being used by enterprises and companies implementing big data. For systems like CRM, ERP the data is generally gathered/exported on to a different system and either you could use flume for streaming those files or use typical hdfs put commands. Typically people use Hadoop if you have a big data problem (hundreds of terabytes) or for data warehouse offloads, if non of them are your concerns then don't go into the pain of implementing Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

We have three different kinds of [data](https://jeremyronk.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/structured-semi-structured-and-unstructured-data/) - Structured (schema based systems like Oracle/MySQL etc.), Unstructured (images, weblogs etc.) and Semi-structured data(XML etc.)

**Structured data** can be stored in database SQL  in table with rows and columns

**Semi-structured data** is information that doesn’t reside in a relational database but that does have some organizational properties that make it easier to analyze. With some process you can store them in relation database (e.g. XML)

**Unstructured data** often include text and multimedia content. Examples include e-mail messages, word processing documents, videos, photos, audio files, presentations, webpages and many other kinds of business documents.

**Depending on type of your data, you will choose the tools to import data into HDFS**.

Your company may use CRM,ERP tools. But we don't exactly know how the data is organized & structured.

If we leave simple HDFS commands like put, copyFromLocal etc to load data into HDFS compatible format, below are the main tools to load data into HDFS

[**Apache Sqoop(TM)**](http://sqoop.apache.org/) is a tool designed for efficiently transferring bulk data between Apache Hadoop and structured datastores such as relational databases. Data from MySQL, SQL Server & Oracle tables can be loaded into HDFS with this tool.

[**Apache Flume**](http://flume.apache.org/) is a distributed, reliable, and available service for efficiently collecting, aggregating, and moving large amounts of log data. It has a simple and flexible architecture based on streaming data flows. It is robust and fault tolerant with tunable reliability mechanisms and many failover and recovery mechanisms.

[**Other tools**](http://thinkbig.teradata.com/leading_big_data_technologies/ingestion-and-streaming-with-storm-kafka-flume/) include **Chukwa,Storm and Kafka**

But other important technology, which is becoming very popular is Spark. It is a Friend & Foe for Hadoop.

[**Spark**](http://spark.apache.org/)  is emerging an good alternative to Hadoop for real time data processing, which may or may not use HDFS as data source.